# GO - get photos from flickr api

Tags: go

I'm new to Go. I'm trying to build a simple app that lets users get photos from flickr by keying in a tag in a form. I'm stuck at my current code (pasted below) as nothing appears on the page /showimage when I click on the submit button. What am I doing wrong in the code?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/showimage", showimage)
    fmt.Println("listening...")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(GetPort(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}

func GetPort() string {
    var port = os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "4747"
        fmt.Println("INFO: No PORT environment variable detected, defaulting to " + port)
    }
    return ":" + port
}

func handler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, rootForm)
}

const rootForm = 
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Flickr photos</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Flickr photos</h1>
            <p>Find photos by tags!</p>
            <form action="/showimage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <input type="text" name="str" value="Type Tags..." id="str">
                <input type="submit" value=".. and see the images!">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>`

var upperTemplate = template.Must(template.New("showimage").Parse(upperTemplateHTML))

func showimage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tag := r.FormValue("str")
    safeTag := url.QueryEscape(tag)
    apiKey := "MYAPIKEY"
    fullUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=%s&tags=%s", apiKey, safeTag)

    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fullUrl, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("NewRequest: ", err)
        return
    }

    resp, requestErr := client.Do(req)
    if requestErr != nil {
        log.Fatal("Do: ", requestErr)
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()



    body, dataReadErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if dataReadErr != nil {
        log.Fatal("ReadAll: ", dataReadErr)
        return
    }

    res := make(map[string]map[string]map[string]interface{}, 0)

    json.Unmarshal(body, &res)

    owner, _ := res["photos"]["photo"]["owner"]
    id, _ := res["photos"]["photo"]["id"]

    queryUrl := fmt.Sprintf("http://flickr.com/photos/%s/%s", owner, id)



    tempErr := upperTemplate.Execute(w, queryUrl)
    if tempErr != nil {
        http.Error(w, tempErr.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

const upperTemplateHTML =
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Display images</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Images</h3>
        <img src="{{html .}}" alt="Image" />
    </body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) http.HandleFunc("showimage", showimage) should be http.HandleFunc("/showimage", showimage)

2) MYAPIKEY is probably not a valid api key.

Comment: thanks! yea its a string of numbers. I've put down my own api key in the code. I've fixed the /showimage code and now it takes me to another page, but the image is broken

Comment: @AUL you can check response body and the image url

Comment: I've got this error: GET http://flickr.com/photos/%!s(%3Cnil%3E)/%!s(%3Cnil%3E) 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @AUL json.Unmarshal(body, &res) probably return a error

Comment: @AUL fullUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=%s&user_id=%s", apiKey, safeTag)
 Here you set input tags to user_id parameter, is that right?

Comment: yes, but I've re-written that code to this: fullUrl := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%stags=%s", apiKey, safeTag). The earlier one was for getting photos with a user's id and incorrect